# cURL to httppost Java in Android and debug output from request

Tags: json, debugging, curl, http-post

This is the script that works:

```
curl -H  'content-type:application/json' -d '{"userrequest": {"username": "testname", "status": 1}}'  http://http://employeestracking.appspot.com/clockin.add_clockin
```

This is what I tried to use in android:
further,How can I see/debug the output?

```
                    HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
                HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost("http://employeestracking.appspot.com/clockin.add_clockin");
                httpost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                httpost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
                System.out.println("2");
                JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
                JSONObject userrequest = new JSONObject();
                HttpResponse response = null;
                try {
                    userrequest.put("username","TestDemo");
                    userrequest.put("status",1);
                    data.put("userrequest", userrequest);
                    System.out.println(data);
                    httpost.getParams().setParameter("data",data);
                    try {
                        response = client.execute(httpost);
                        System.out.println(response);
                    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

this is what i get from the server:

```
41.132.228.221 - - [26/Jan/2012:01:18:29 -0800] "POST /clockin.add_clockin HTTP/1.1" 400 663 - "curl/7.19.7 (i486-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 OpenSSL/0.9.8k zlib/1.2.3.3 libidn/1.15"
```

41.132.228.221 - - [26/Jan/2012:01:18:55 -0800] "POST /clockin.add_clockin HTTP/1.1" 200 151 - "curl/7.19.7 (i486-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 OpenSSL/0.9.8k zlib/1.2.3.3 libidn/1.15"
0.1.0.1 - - [26/Jan/2012:01:31:52 -0800] "GET /tasks/train HTTP/1.1" 404 124 - "AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine)"
41.132.228.221 - - [26/Jan/2012:01:37:17 -0800] "POST /clockin.add_clockin HTTP/1.1" 500 663 - -

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I replaced

```
httpost.getParams().setParameter("data",data);
```

with:

```
StringEntity se = new StringEntity(data.toString());
httpost.setEntity(se);
```

and it worked